# Remote access to namenode is not allowed despite the services are already started.

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, netstat

I successfully installed and run Hadoop on a single machine whose ip is 192.168.1.109 (In fact it is actually an Ubuntu instance running on virtual box ) . 
When typing jps it shows

**2473 DataNode**

**2765 TaskTracker**

**3373 Jps**

**2361 NameNode**

**2588 SecondaryNameNode**

**2655 JobTracker**

This should mean that the hadoop is up and running.
Running commands like ./hadoop fs -ls is fine and produces the expected result.

But If I try to connect it from my windows box whose ip is 192.168.1.80 by writing
Java code's HDFS API to connect it as follows:

**Configuration conf = new Configuration();**

**FileSystem hdfs = null;**

**Path filenamePath = new Path(FILE_NAME);**

**hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);** <-- the problem occurred at this line

when I run the code, the error displayed as follows:

**11/12/07 20:37:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:39 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).**

**11/12/07 20:37:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.1.109:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).**

**java.net.ConnectException: Call to /192.168.1.109:9000 failed on  connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information**

To make sure if the socket is already opened and waits for the incoming connections on the hadoop serer, I netstat on the ubuntu box
the result shows as follows:

**tcp        0      0 localhost:51201         *:*                     LISTEN      2765/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:50020                 *:*                     LISTEN      2473/java**
**tcp        0      0 localhost:9000          *:*                     LISTEN      2361/java**
**tcp        0      0 localhost:9001          *:*                     LISTEN      2655/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:50090                 *:*                     LISTEN      2588/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:11211                 *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:40843                 *:*                     LISTEN      2473/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:58699                 *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:50060                 *:*                     LISTEN      2765/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:50030                 *:*                     LISTEN      2655/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:53966                 *:*                     LISTEN      2655/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:epmd                  *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:55826                 *:*                     LISTEN      2588/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:50070                 *:*                     LISTEN      2361/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:52822                 *:*                     LISTEN      2361/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:55672                 *:*                     LISTEN      -**
**tcp        0      0 *:50010                 *:*                     LISTEN      2473/java**
**tcp        0      0 *:50075                 *:*                     LISTEN      2473/java**

I noticed that if the local address column is something like localhost:9000 (starts with localhost: not *:)
It will not be able to be connected from remote host or even in it own box in some case.
I tried telnet localhost 9000  it works, I means it can connect to the port but If I use telnet 192.168.1.109 9000
The errors displays like

**$ telnet 192.168.1.109 9000
Trying 192.168.1.109...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused**

I have spent almost a week figuring out the issue I am really exhausted now and I hope someone can help me.

Note: I am not sure if namenode by default refuses remote connection. Do I need to change some settings in order for it to allow
remote connections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the value of `fs.default.name` to `hdfs://106.77.211.187:9000` from `hdfs://localhost:9000`in core-site.xml for both the client and the NameNode. Replace the IP address with the IP address of the node on which the NameNode is running or with the hostname.

Was able to `telnet 106.77.211.187 9000` and here is the output of `netstat -a | grep 9000`

> tcp6       0      0 106.77.211.187:9000     [::]:*                  LISTEN
>   tcp6       0      0 106.77.211.187:50753    106.77.211.187%819:9000 ESTABLISHED
>   tcp6       0      0 106.77.211.187:9000     106.77.211.187%81:50753 ESTABLISHED

As to why, the source code look like the following for fs.default.name set to localhost

> ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9000);
>   socket.bind(localhost);

Because bind address is assigned to localhost, the namenode process only can accept connection from localhost. If bind address is assigned to the name of machine name or ip address, then namenode process can accept any connection from remote machine.

Comment: Why does it have to be 106.77.211.187. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Updated the response why `fs.default.name` should be set to ip-address/hostname instead of localhost.

Comment: Note that now the property is called `fs.defaultFs` https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-2789

Answer (score 3):

I replaced all localhost with its ip address in all configuration file, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check  `/etc/hosts` file and make sure you have the IP associated with the fully qualified name (FQN) of your node. Example:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1            localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.100.11 node1.mydomain.com node1
192.168.100.12 node2.mydomain.com node2
```

In my case, I had line `127.0.0.1  node1.mydomain.com` which was definetly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but was able to get it fixed by doing the following. I had the hadoop master and slaves as CentOS7 VirtualBox VMs and I couldn't access web GUIs from the windows host by using the IP address and port of the Master node. Make sure you follow the steps given below to get it fixed;

1. As mentioned in the others posts, make sure the /etc/hosts file is correctly populated

> ```
> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
>
> ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
>
> 172.10.2.20     hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster      hdp-master1
>
> 172.10.2.21     hdp-slave1.hadoop.cluster       hdp-slave1
>
> 172.10.2.22     hdp-slave2.hadoop.cluster       hdp-slave2
> ```

2. And in all your hadoop xml files use the fully qualified hostname or ip  instead of localhost, as others have mentioned
3. Add the following entry to **hdfs-site.xml** to make the web gui port to run from ip instead of `0.0.0.0:9870`

> ```
> <property>
>         <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
>         <value>hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster:9870</value>
> </property>
> ```

4. Add the following entry to **yarn-site.xml** to make the resource manager web gui port to run from ip instead of `0.0.0.0:8088`

> ```
> <property>
>         <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
>         <value>hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster:8088</value>
> </property>
>
> <property>
>         <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
>         <value>hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster:8090</value>
> </property>
> ```

5. Stop and Start all services using start-all.sh. Just to be safe I ran `hdfs namenode -format` first before restarting services
6. Use `netstat -tulnp` on master node and make sure web ports run based on the ip

   > ```
   > netstat -tulnp
   >
   > tcp 0 0 172.16.3.20:8088 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 14651/java
   > tcp 0 0 172.16.3.20:9870 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 14167/java
   > ```
7. Even after all that, I still couldn't access from the windows host and the culprit was the firewall on the hadoop nodes. So stop stop the firewall on all master and slave node as below

> ```
> Check status
> ------------
> systemctl status firewalld
>
> Stop Firewall
> -------------
> systemctl stop firewalld
>
> Disable from Startup
> --------------------
> systemclt disable firewalld
> ```

Now you should be able to access from the windows host through a web browser. I had entries added to windows hosts file so the even the following worked

> ```
> http://hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster:9870
> http://hdp-master1.hadoop.cluster:8088
> ```

Hope this helps